# Efficient iteration over 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python and Numpy to do some data analysis.

I have a large 3D matrix (NxNxN), where each cell is again a matrix, this time a 3x3 matrix. Calling the matrix `data`, it looks like this:

```
data[N,N,N,3,3]
```

I need to find the eigenvalues of all the 3x3 matrices, and for that I use Numpy's `eigvals` routine, but it takes ages to do. Right now I pretty much do this:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            a = np.linalg.eigvals(data[i,j,k,:,:])
```

For N = 256, this takes about an hour. Any ideas on how to make this more efficient?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: have you profiled?  i suspect you're spending much more time in eigvals than you are iterating.

Comment: eigvals takes about three orders of magnitude longer by my timeit calculations, so I don't think changing the iteration is going to affect anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973849/efficient-iteration-over-3d-array/6973890#6973890) is nicer than nested loops, aesthetically speaking. But I don't think it will make your code that much faster. My testing suggests that iteration is not your bottleneck.

```
>>> bigdata = numpy.arange(256 * 256 * 256 * 3 * 3).reshape(256, 256, 256, 3, 3)
>>> %timeit numpy.linalg.eigvals(bigdata[100, 100, 100, :, :])
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.6 us per loop
```

So underestimating:

```
>>> .000052 * 256 * 256 * 256 / 60
14.540253866666665
```

That's 14 minutes minimum on my computer, which is pretty new. Let's see how long the loops take...

```
>>> def just_loops(N):
...     for i in xrange(N):
...         for j in xrange(N):
...             for k in xrange(N):
...                 pass
... 
>>> %timeit just_loops(256)
1 loops, best of 3: 350 ms per loop
```

Orders of magnitude smaller, as DSM said. Even the work of slicing the array alone is more substantial:

```
>>> def slice_loops(N, data):
...     for i in xrange(N):
...         for j in xrange(N):
...             for k in xrange(N):
...                 data[i, j, k, :, :]
... 
>>> %timeit slice_loops(256, bigdata)
1 loops, best of 3: 33.5 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! From your tests it does indeed look like there is not much to be done to make it faster.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there is a good way to do this in NumPy, but in general, `itertools.product` is faster than nested loops over ranges.

```
from itertools import product

for i, j, k in product(xrange(N), xrange(N), xrange(N)):
    a = np.linalg.eigvals(data[i,j,k,:,:])
```

Comment: In this case -- since N is so small -- I actually find that the loop overhead is roughly twice as large with the product loop than it is with the nested ranges.  I still like the product approach better, because it's flatter and the overhead is negligible here anyway.

Comment: That's interesting. it would seem to me that creating 65536 + 256 inner lists would be slower (although I didn't expect it to make a huge difference).

Answer (score 2):

since all the calculation are independent, you can use multiprocessing module to speed up the calculation if you have a multi-core processor.